# Purposed Cassandra 2.1 setup for unit tests?

Tags: java, performance, unit-testing, cassandra

I currently wonder what options do I have to configure Cassandra for unit testing.

Currently I just use a SSD drive and set the Cassandra directory differently and start the tests loading test scenarios. It is dead slow but I reuse the server and heal the scenarios (restore instead of delete and start over) but beside from that what else can I do?

I also pondered if I can create a ram drive and mount it just for those tests.

What options are useful in conjunction with tests without introducing functional differences that make acceptance tests worthless?

Is there an in-memory replacement like one replaces MySQL/PostgreSQL with H2 for unit testing?

Comment: A good blog post I found http://christopher-batey.blogspot.de/2014/06/unit-testing-java-cassandra-applications.html

Answer (score 2):

I'd avoid using a real Cassandra instance for your unit testing, it'll make your tests brittle and will mean they won't be able to run anywhere. Theres a couple of options for unit testing your dao's without a real Cassandra needing to be available.

One option is [Cassandra Unit](https://github.com/jsevellec/cassandra-unit). This works by starting up an embedded Cassandra for you to connect to, you can create keyspaces/tables and insert data to prime it just like a real Cassandra.

Another option is [Scassandra](http://www.scassandra.org/). This starts up a stubbed Cassandra and needs to be primed with what to return. The great thing about Scassandra is that you can test all of your error scenarios such as timeouts, NoHostAvailable etc.

Comment: The Cassandra Unit option I already use. I also start an embedded cassandra server within the JDK. I just dislike having additional files to compare with. I use java methods and classes to specify the scenario and expected results.

Scassandra looks interesting. It is actually what a mocking solution would look like but with more afford and simplier usage (as far as I can tell)